# Can't Execute Query when downloading a file from blob storage Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, encoding, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download an SQL file from a blob container. The download works and I get the file, the problem is with the encoding, when I execute the command ExecuteNonQuery, the database give an error saying that there was errors creating the Tables. I have debugged my way to find that the string that I get after downloading the file contains "\n"

BlobAccess.cs

```
        public  string GetBlob(string fileName)
        {
            string connectionString ="constring";
            // Setup the connection to the storage account
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

            // Connect to the blob storage
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Connect to the blob container
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("storage");
            // Connect to the blob file
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{fileName}");
            // Get the blob file as text
            var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
            {
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
            };


            string contents =  blob.DownloadTextAsync(Encoding.UTF8, null, blobRequestOptions, null).Result;

            return contents;

        }
```

Program.cs

```
            try
            {

                string scripttocreatetables = blobAccess.GetBlob("test.sql");
                

                var conn = new SqlConnection(dbstring);
                try
                {
                        conn.Open();
                        var cmd = new SqlCommand("query", conn);
                        cmd.CommandText = scripttocreatetables;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var mh = new MonitorHelper(vcCustomer);
                    var itemid = mh.SetStart("Database");
                    mh.SetError(itemid, "Database connection failed:  " + e.Message);
                    mh.SetEnd(itemid, 0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                    conn.Close();
                    return;
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
}
```

Comment: Doing `.Result` may well be a bad idea. You should really `await` async operations

Comment: How does your SQL look like?

Comment: Are you sure your file is UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried  reproducing the scenario in my lab, but couldn’t find the issue you are facing.

I tried to download SQL file from blob (Also tried with txt file) getting the proper data there is no "\n"

[image]

The Out put of SQL file

[image]

After getting data from SQL file pass it to the **CommandText** to execute query.Try this code to execute query

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```